# How set where in templates using jpa in CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, criteriaquery

I am beginner in java EE and I need know, how set a clausule **where** in this code of criteria

```
public <T> List<T> findEntity(Class<T> entityClass) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> entityRoot = criteria.from(entityClass);
    criteria.select(entityRoot);
    criteria.orderBy(order);
    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

They will notice that I am using templates in java (**`<T>`**) to make this code work with various entities from my database.

Then I pass the sql (in postgresql) code and the entity class.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE activity
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  _modified timestamp without time zone,
  _user integer,
  _enable boolean,
)
```

And class entity

```
public class activity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "activity_id_activity_seq" )
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "actividad_id_actividad_seq", sequenceName = "actividad_id_actividad_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 110 )
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "_modified")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modified;
    @Column(name = "_enable")
    private Boolean enable;
    @Column(name = "_user")
    private Integer user;
    .......
}
```

I need to know is how to add a where clause in the code of the function **findEntity** using methods template.

The where clause of criteria should be matching the column **_Enable**, this column this column mentioned is repeated in 4 tables in my database, so you note that it is better to reuse code in that function.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to add `where()` clause:

```java
public static <T> List<T> findEntity(Class<T> entityClass, boolean isEnabled) {
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> entityRoot = criteria.from(entityClass);
    criteria.select(entityRoot);

    criteria.where(builder.equal(
            entityRoot.get("enable"), //path expression
            builder.parameter(Boolean.class, "isEnabled")) //parameter expression
    );

    criteria.orderBy(order);
    return em.createQuery(criteria)
            .setParameter("isEnabled", isEnabled)
            .getResultList();
}
```

The  `entityRoot.get("enable")` statement defines `Path<String>` expression. This is equivalent of `a.enable` which uses a colon to denote a parameter in JPQL, i.e.

```
SELECT a FROM Activity a WHERE a.enable = :isEnabled
```

To build conditional expression one must also create a `ParameterExpression<Boolean>` which corresponds to the parameter of typed query that executes our criteria.

Using this approach you can easily extend your generic method with new parameters.

I hope it helps.